# Ubuntu виснет при загрузке

Tags: ubuntu, swap

вчера вечером завис компьютер, я его хардресетнул.
Вылез plymouth и первой ошибкой было что-то связанное с файлом подкачки, мол не удается его найти или подключить. И дальше все приводило в emergency mode.
Я воспользовался [этой инструкцией](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru) и подключил файл подкачки. После этого plymouth при загрузке исчез, и система начала грузится, как и раньше, но только намертво зависает, не доходя до экрана с выбором пользователя.

В систему все еще можно войти через recovery, но при такой загрузке все равно присутствует ошибка о файле подкачки.

А вот если в терминале набрать swapon --show, то показывает:

/swapfile file 1024M   0B   -2

Я пересмотрел кучу подобных вопросов-ответов, но так и не знаю, что именно у меня не так.

Уточню, что сегодня утром решил попробовать обновить версию до 20.04(до этого стояла 18.04).
Ближе к концу, компьютер опять завис, пришлось снова делать хард ресет. Но все то же самое: загрузка системы виснет, вход возможен только из recovery.

Вот вывод некоторых команд:

cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=55E1-F6BA  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sda2 00bee490-56fe-409f-977e-cfb2d757c43d ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

fdisk -l

```
Диск /dev/loop0: 97,6 MiB, 101777408 байт, 198784 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop1: 55,33 MiB, 58007552 байт, 113296 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop2: 956 KiB, 978944 байт, 1912 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop3: 255,58 MiB, 267980800 байт, 523400 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop4: 2,17 MiB, 2273280 байт, 4440 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop5: 2,45 MiB, 2555904 байт, 4992 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop6: 276 KiB, 282624 байт, 552 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop7: 458,69 MiB, 480952320 байт, 939360 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/sda: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 байт, 976773168 секторов
Disk model: TOSHIBA DT01ACA0
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 4096 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 4096 байт / 4096 байт
Тип метки диска: gpt
Идентификатор диска: 2803166A-23F1-4E18-8497-3BC24E7C881B

Устр-во     начало     Конец   Секторы Размер Тип
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI
/dev/sda2  1050624 976771071 975720448 465,3G Файловая система Linux


Диск /dev/loop8: 62,9 MiB, 65105920 байт, 127160 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop9: 29,9 MiB, 31334400 байт, 61200 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop10: 589,22 MiB, 617832448 байт, 1206704 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop11: 30,27 MiB, 31735808 байт, 61984 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт
```

blkid

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="00bee490-56fe-409f-977e-cfb2d757c43d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="38c473b2-a4ef-4496-8c3a-05504e14ad13"
```

Ну в общем, такая вот ситуация. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем дело.